# Java class definiton?

Tags: java, class

So I'm fairly new to the language, and my teacher just gave us this asignment where we create a game using 5 classes. He gave us the class names, and told us to go off of the code in our text book.

From the assignment sheet: 
1. Create a Pig Game for exactly two players, a user is one and the computer is the other.  You will have to create exactly five classes and they are:
     a. Die
     b. Pair of Die
     c. Player 
     d. PigGame or PigReferee 
     e. PlayPig (this will contain the main driver)

Code given:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Die {
    private final int MIN_FACES = 4;

    private static Random generator = new Random();
    private int  numFaces; //number of sides on the die
    private int faceValue; //current value showing on the die

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    //  Defaults to a six-sided die. Initial face value is 1.                            |
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    public Die(){
        numFaces = 6;
        faceValue = 1;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    //Explicitly sets the size of the die. Defaults to a size of six if the parameter is |
    //invalid. Initial face value is 1.                                                  |
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    public Die(int faces){
        if (faces < MIN_FACES){
            numFaces = 6;
        }
        else{
            numFaces = faces;
        }
        faceValue = 1;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    //  Rolls the die and returns the result.                                            |
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    public int roll(){
        faceValue = generator.nextInt(numFaces) + 1;
        return faceValue;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    //  Returns the current faceValue.                                                   |
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    public int getFaceValue(){
        return faceValue;
    }
}
```

So my question is, is Die the only current class, or does the "public int roll" count as a class as well. What makes a class? Thanks, Dizzy

Comment: `public int roll(...)` is a *method*, not a *class*. You'll want to read up on Java methods and classes in a decent tutorial as that's the best place to learn this stuff.

Comment: The keyword `class` is what defines a class in Java. If it were to be a class, it should have the keyword `class`

Answer (score 1):

Die is your only current class. You can tell because the keyword **class** is used when it is defined. `public int roll()` is a method inside of the Die class.

You can also normally tell what is a class is because each class will have their own .java file named after that class. So your Die class should be defined in a Die.java file. The other four classes you need to create will also each be in their own .java files.

Comment: Not necessary that all classes should be in their own files. A single java file can contain multiple classes, but only one of them should be  public and the file name should be that public class's name

Answer (score 0):

`Die` is only your class here. Just like you made the Die class you will have to make the other classes. Then you will have to use what is called **`Inheritance`**. The main class will be i suppose `PlayPig`.
Inheritance is very important topic in java and i don't know how your teacher gave you a project without explaining it. Anyhow here are some links for your problem.

[1st link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) [2nd link](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-inheritance) [3rd link](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Java-Beginners/26449-Inheritance-java-Example.html)